# Getting currentPage from Experience Fragment with Apache Sling Dynamic Include enabled

Tags: aem

When trying to get `currentPage` in experience fragment via dispatcher I'm always receiving the `resourcePage`. When trying to access `currentPage` directly on author/publish environment I'm getting expected results - the page that contains the experience fragment.

I tried the standard approach with `@Inject Page currentPage`, but it breaks when reaching for the page via dispatcher and returns the same result as `resourcePage`. `request` does not contain anything worth mentioning.

Edit: I figured out that caused this: Apache Sling Dynamic Include.

Right now my only solution is to get `pathInfo` from the request, convert it to path and find it to page using `PageManager`. There should a simpler way I cannot see.